# Swift 3 / How to reuse extensions

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to save code and refactor.

In my project I'm using the following `adMobBanner` extension in several `UIViewController`s.

The whole extension is reusable, I just need to change the name of the ViewController:

```
extension MyVC: GADInterstitialDelegate {
```

But since I'm using it in several classes, the length of those classes exceeds unnecessarily.

Is there some kind of way to reuse the extension? Something like:

```
func myExtension(vc: UIViewController) {
    extension vc: GADInterstitialDelegate {
    ....
    }
}
```

Called by `myExtension(MyViewController)`

I know that this code is nonsense, but it provides the idea I would like to transpose. Is there anything like that? Or what would be another option to save lines of codes for extensions with repeated code? Help is very appreciated.

My Extension:

```
extension MyViewController: GADInterstitialDelegate {

    // MARK: - Setup Ads
    func setupAds() {
        // Setup our interstitial ad initially
        interstitial.delegate = self
        interstitial.load(GADRequest())


    }

    // MARK: - Load Interstitial Ad
    func loadFullScreenAd() {
        // GADInterstitial's are single use. You have to create a new GADInterstitial for each presentation
        // So, if you'd like to show more than one GADInterstitial in your apps session we need this
        // This func will be used to create a new GADInterstitial after one has been displayed and dismissed
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: getAdmobInterstitial())


        interstitial.delegate = self
        interstitial.load(GADRequest())

    }


    // MARK: - Show Interstitial Ad
    func showFullScreenAd() {
        // Call this function when you want to present the interstitial ad
        // ie. game over, transition to another vc, etc...
        // Make sure you give atleast a few seconds for this ad to load before atempting to present it
        // For example, don't try to present this ad in viewDidAppear

        // Check if the interstitial ad is loaded before trying to present it

        if self.interstitial.isReady {

            self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
    }


    // MARK: - GADInterstitial Delegate Methods
    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial!) {
        print("interstitialDidReceiveAd")
        showFullScreenAd()
    }

    func interstitialWillPresentScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial!) {
        print("interstitialWillPresentScreen")
        // If you needed to pause anything in your app this would be the place to do it
        // ie. sounds, game state, etc...
    }

    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial!) {
        print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
        // The GADInterstitial has been shown and dismissed by the user
        // Lets load another one for the next time we want to show a GADInterstitial

        //loadFullScreenAd()

        // If you paused anything in the interstitialWillPresentScreen delegate method this is where you would resume it
    }

    func interstitial(_ ad: GADInterstitial!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
        print("interstitial didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the common superclass of all affected view controllers (probably `UIViewController` itself), then you can use the code in all subclasses.

Comment: so `extension UIViewController: GADInterstitialDelegate {` ?

Comment: Yes,  exactly  :-)

Comment: thank you very much. i'll accept your answer since it's the same logic as in the second answer and yours was first

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me so far was to create an own file named like `"Name regarding to the content about-extension of class` and then I put the file in a group folder named `Extensions`. So in your case I would call the file like that:

```
GADInterstitialDelegate-UIViewControllerExtension.swift
```

And the code inside like that:

```
extension UIViewController: GADInterstitialDelegate {
// your reusable code
}
```

It's just my approach and I think there are also other good ones

Comment: thank you very much for your help and input. but i'll accept the other answer since it's the same logic and to be fair: he was first (based on time). but upvote for your time and effort

Comment: Welcome, sure thats true. I was just to slow how to describe it in the best way. In the end its quite the same except with the hint to the separate file